# Merging 2 Functions

Tags: php, mysql, function, class

I have below 2 function in same class.
Is it possible to use single function instead of 2?

```
class c1
{
   function f1 ()
   {
      sql statement 1
   }

function f2 ()
   {
      sql statement 2
      sql statement 3
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes? Copy paste the contents of `f2` in the end of `f1`? Am I missing something trivial here? There's probably a reason that there's two seperate functions?

Comment: You're the programmer so it's your possibility to make a new function `function f3() { f1(); f2();}`

Comment: @PKeidel It's in a class, so it'd be `$this->f1(); $this->f2();`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Oh dear. Yes, of couse.

Comment: try to use all queries in single instead using two or more function.

Comment: I need to call this function with different requirement. function 1 and function 2 are requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class c1
{
   function f1 ()
   {
      sql statement 1
     sql statement 2
      sql statement 3
   }


}
```

OR

```
class c1
{
   function f1 ()
   {
      sql statement 1
   f2 ()
   }

function f2 ()
   {
      sql statement 2
      sql statement 3
   }
}
```

Comment: I prefer your first suggestion. In first function i need sql statement 1 and second function statement 1 and 2. In your first suggestion, How would i call same function but with different requirement?

Comment: Pass different parameters to indicate different functionality. Eg f1(1) for insert, f1(2) for update etc.. Using parameters you can define your  requirement

Comment: Thanks. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Better than that, why don't you do all those SQL statements in one?

```
<?php
class c1
{
   function f1 ()
   {
        //sql statement 1, 2 & 3
   }

}
?>
```

Comment: In first function i need sql statement 1 and second function statement 1 and 2. How would i call same function but with different requirement?